# Highcharts rendered more than the size of the container

Tags: html, css, dotnethighcharts, gwt-highcharts

When I try to load highcharts on my html page for a specific div, it is displaying larger than the size of div. Simply it is displaying irrespective of the div size. Can someone help? If I re-size my div, the chart must re-size to fit its parent div size.

Comment: Seeing some code would help. We can't see what you see.

Comment: What Code do you exactly require? Html, Css ?

Comment: a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be ideal.

Comment: A fiddle is unnecessary. This site now has a code previewer. We obviously need both your relevant html and css.

Comment: Thanks guys, I solved it. We need to define the css for the ID to which highchart is rendering the data instead of defining  a class to use in its parent div.